# How to show current location on Google-Maps-for-Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, ruby-on-rails-4, gmaps4rails

I have the `gem 'gmaps4rails'` installed and currently the setup is to show the location:

```
<div style='width: 800px;'>
  <div id="map" style='width: 800px; height: 400px;'></div>
</div>

<script>
    handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
    handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
        markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);
        handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
        handler.fitMapToBounds();
        handler.getMap().setZoom(16);
    });
</script>
```

I would like to show the current location on the map as well. Any ideas on how to implement that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Append current user location hash into your array of location hash and Rest will be handled by Gmap4Rails**

```
def show
    @las = La.find(params[:id])
    @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@las) do |la, marker|
      marker.lat la.latitude
      marker.lng la.longitude
    end
    append_cur_location 
end 

def append_cur_location
  @hash << { :lat=>action[0], :lng=>action[1]}
end

def action
   @lat_lng = cookies[:lat_lng].split("|")
end
```

**Extras: If you want separate image for current user location.use below**

> { :lat=>12.9698, :lng=>77.7499, :picture=>{:url=>user_image_path,
>   :width=>32, :height=>32} }

Comment: Thanks for the reply @krishnar!! Unfortunatly the map is grey now and doesn't show anything. No zoom-in or out is allowed as well.

Comment: Nope no error, the page appears correctly and only the map is grey. I checked the console as well, and no errors seem to appear there too.

Comment: I updated append_cur_location method.check it. Remove brackets over hash

Comment: It works, thanks @ krishnar!!!  I have a couple of more questions... how can I get it to auto zoom so I can view both locations on the map? How can I change the color of the current location pin?

Comment: @Dev I am ready to help. I mentioned in extras that you can set different image for current user location

Comment: Thanks @krishnar for the help, where does the extra code you provided go? I'm not sure how to implement this.

Comment: { :lat=>12.9698, :lng=>77.7499, :picture=>{:url=>user_image_path, :width=>32, :height=>32} }

Comment: And I put this where?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155538/discussion-between-krishnar-and-dev).

Comment: Thanks for the info @krishnar I got it to work!! I was wondering how can I change the current location marker as well?